# QGIS bat file for 64 bit build

Tags: qgis, windows-7, compile

I am trying to build QGIS on a 64 bit machine with Windows 7 SP1.

My bat file is as follows:

```
@echo off

set VS90COMNTOOLS=%Program Files (x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
call "%Program Files (x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" 
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include
set LIB=%LIB%;%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
path %PATH%;%Program Files (x86)%\CMake 2.8\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin
@set GRASS_PREFIX=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/grass/grass-6.4.3
@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include
@set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib

@cmd
```

This shows me the error

```
C:\BUILD>qgis.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have checked all the paths but I'm not able to solve the problem.

Comment: I think this `%Program Files (x86)%` should be just `Program Files (x86)` in line 9

Comment: %Program Files (x86)% should be %PROGRAMFILES%,
%PROGRAMFILES% is normally "C:\Program Files (x86)"

Answer (score 2):

*Answer based on @klewis comment :*

In your code, try changing `%Program Files (x86)%` into `%PROGRAMFILES%

Check the environment variable **PROGRAMFILES** in the "System variables" list. It should point to a value like : "C:\Program Files (x86)".

[image: Windows environment variables]

[image: Variables]

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative build system based on [NextGIS borsch](https://github.com/nextgis/nextgisqgis). No additional bat files needed. The requirements are:

- VC
- Python
- git
- CMake

Warning! This is lite version of QGIS (remove many features for stable and speed).